# Existence of naive bimodule resolutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, homological-algebra, bimodules

Let $A$ be an $R$-algebra over a commutative ring $R$.

Under appropriate finiteness conditions (A finitely generated as $R$-module, $R$ Noetherian), any finitely generated $A$-bimodule $M$ is known to have a *free* resolution, that is, a complex
$$ \ldots (A \otimes_{R} A)^{r_2} \to (A \otimes_{R} A)^{r_1} \to (A \otimes_{R} A)^{r_0} $$
of $A$-bimodules with non-zero integers $r_i$ and only one non-vanishing homology, which is at zero degree and isomorphic to $M$.

Are there any "good" necessary or sufficient criteria known for the bimodule $M$ to have a "*naive*" resolution of the form
$$ \ldots A^{r_2} \to A^{r_1} \to A^{r_0}$$
viewing $A$ as $A$-bimodule in a natural way?

Does the category of such bimodules have any notable properties?

To avoid boredom, let us assume that $A$ is not just the base ring $R$.

Any answer or mention of reference will be appreciated. Thank you for reading!